# Linuxのシェルスクリプトで、文字列を検索するフィールドを指定する

Tags: linux, shellscript

やり方がわかりません。

番号｜名前｜身長｜体重
を記録したテーブルがあります。

ここから、身長170センチ以上180センチ以下の人を抽出したいのですが、

```
grep $a ファイル名
```

$aに170や180の身長を入れてwhileで回して検索していたのですが
このやり方では体重とかぶって正確な値が出ない場合があります。
（体重１７０キロの人が抽出されました）
そこで列指定で、検索したいのですがやり方が思いつきません。

いい方法があればご教授ください。

Comment: この場合、grep よりも awk の方が良さそうです。`awk -F'|' '$3>=170&&$3<=180' table_file`  # 「行指定で検索」ではなく、「列指定で検索」でしょうか？

Comment: 列指定で検索です。訂正しました。
タイトルどおり、フィールドを指定とかけばよかったです。
区切り文字の「｜」はスペースやカンマなどにも変更可能ですか？

Comment: はい、可能です。デフォルトがスペースとタブなので、その場合は `-F` で指定しなくても構いません。また、セパレータには正規表現を使うことができますので、例えば `awk -F'[| ,]' ...` とすると `|`, スペース、カンマ全てがセパレータとして扱われます。

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F \| '$3 >= 170 && $3 <=  180 {print $0}' data.txt
```

ですかね。

`-F \|`区切り文字の指定。`|`だとパイプとして認識されるので`\`でエスケープします。

各行に対して、
`$3 >= 170 && $3 <= 180` `|`で区切った3番目のフィールドが170以上180以下の時に･･･
`{print $0}` `$0`(行全体)を表示

と言う動作になります。

Answer (score 0):

「シェルスクリプト」と言われてるので、あえて awk 使わず区切り文字の指定に `IFS` を使う例を。

```
is_height_in_range() {
  local min=$1
  local max=$2
  local line="$3"

  IFS="|"
  set -- ${line}
  [ "$3" -ge "$min" ] && [ "$3" -le "$max" ]
  return
}

IFS=
while read line; do
  is_height_in_range 170 180 "$line" || continue
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

`local` 使ってるので POSIX 互換ではないですが、たいていのシェルで動くと思います。

`read` が 0 以外のステータスを返すと `while` ループから抜けてしまうので、ファイル末尾に改行がないと最終行が無視されますが、回答における本質ではないし実用上はあまり問題ないかと思うのでシンプルさを優先しました。

Comment: `set -- ${line}` これは何をするものですか？

Comment: `set` のオプション以外の引数 (`${line}` が `-` で始まる可能性があるので、通常 `--` を前に入れて、`${line}` がオプションと解釈されないようにします) は、位置パラメータと解釈されます。

`${line}` は通常の変数展開ですが、展開結果は `IFS` にしたがって解釈されるので、`$1`, `$2`, ... には IFS、すなわち `|` で区切った値が入ります。

参考: [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)